# newer gcc for cygwin

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, cygwin

I use `cygwin` to compile my `C++` programs but it uses `gcc 3.4.4`, is there a newer version of it for `cygwin`, or at least a port of newer versions of `gcc` to `windows`?

Comment: My Cygwin installation has gcc 4.5.3 -- not the newest, but newer than what you have. Run `setup.exe` and upgrade it.

Comment: It's also easy to get a much newer version of GCC for Windows via MinGW, but MinGW is a rather different animal than GCC with Cygwin since there's no POSIX emulation.  MinGW is a compiler for Windows that happens to be GCC; Cygwin is a POSIX environment (including GCC) that runs on Windows.

Comment: My cygwin has `gcc 4.7.2`: I compiled `gcc` from sources to be able to use the latest stable `gcc` version. The time to build `gcc` is a bit long but it works like a charm.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I'm not sure how you got anything newer than 3.4.4 without compiling your own version.  The official Cygwin package for GCC is still at 3.4.4 (as of 4/29/2013): http://cygwin.com/packages/gcc/

Comment: @jfritz42: Hmm, I'll have to check when I get home to my Windows machine.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I may have figured it out.  Cygwin has separate "gcc4*" packages.  I was only looking at "gcc*", which is locked to 3.4.4.  After installing gcc4, I have GCC 4.5.3.

Answer (score 1):

Install the "gcc4" package (not "gcc") to get GCC 4.5.3 or (optionally) an even later one.

Kind of hard to find!  This confused me for a while too.